# Error in mysql time query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
  `rstrnt`.`rstrnt_id` 
FROM
  (`rstrnt`) 
  JOIN `rstrnt_timing` 
    ON `rstrnt_timing`.`rstrnt_id` = `rstrnt`.`rstrnt_id` 
WHERE (
    ` rstrnt_timing`.`time_from` < (
      '17:22:14' + INTERVAL  rstrnt.ex_time MINUTE
    )
  ) 
  AND (
     rstrnt_timing.time_to > (
      '17:22:14' + INTERVAL  rstrnt.ex_time MINUTE
    )
  )
```

This  query shows error while running.

**Error Code: 1271**

**Illegal mix of collations for operation '<'**

Comment: What are the data types of `time_from` and `time_from`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Reason You are getting and error

The left operand of `INTERVAL` should be `DATETIIME` type. `INTERVAL` operator always returns DATETIME (or NULL for invalid DATETIME formatted value)

So you are trying to compare `TIME` and `DATETIME` values. That's why MySQL produces

> 'Error Code: 1271 Illegal mix of collations for operation '<'

### How to Fix it

`ADDTIME()` function give us same functionality with `INTERVAL` for `TIME` type. But extra `00` hour and `00` second required to add MINUTE. Following query adds `5 MINUTE` for certain time.

```
mysql> SELECT ADDTIME('17:22:14', CONCAT('00:', 5, ':00'));
+----------------------------------------------+
| ADDTIME('17:22:14', CONCAT('00:', 5, ':00')) |
+----------------------------------------------+
| 17:27:14                                     |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

Now, your query could be converted as follows.

```
    ...
    `rstrnt_timing`.`time_from` < (
      ADDTIME('17:22:14', CONCAT('00:', rstrnt.ex_time, ':00'))
    )
    ...
```

### How To Handle TIME orverflow

`ADDTIME()` produces NULL when MINUTE is greater than 59. Here is overflow safe version. (SECOND overflow is easy if you understand this.)

```
SELECT ADDTIME('17:22:14', CONCAT(CAST((70 / 60) AS UNSIGNED),':', 70 % 60, ':00')) AS dt;
+----------+
| dt       |
+----------+
| 18:32:14 |
+----------+

SELECT ADDTIME('17:22:14', CONCAT(CAST((10 / 60) AS UNSIGNED),':', 10 % 60, ':00')) AS dt;
+----------+
| dt       |
+----------+
| 17:32:14 |
+----------+

SELECT ADDTIME('23:59:14', CONCAT(CAST((7000 / 60) AS UNSIGNED),':', 7000 % 60, ':00')) AS dt;
+-----------+
| dt        |
+-----------+
| 141:39:14 |
+-----------+
```

Comment: Still getting the same error : 
Error Code: 1271
Illegal mix of collations for operation '<'

Comment: @ArjunRaj Sorry, I have updated. If you still have problem, We will sincerely appreciate if you post your schema and sample data on sqlFiddle. This is very convenient way for answering.

Comment: Thanks alot bro... 
ADDTIME('17:22:14', CONCAT('00:', '70', ':00')) - in this case it return NULL [ it only takes 0-59 ]. Can you lease help me to solve this?